# Hypothesis test (2 groups, daily readings per person in each group)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, repeated-measures

I am running an experiment: there are 2 groups of people and a reading is taken for every person every day. So I have this dataset:

**Group A**

```
p_a1: {d1, d2, d3, ...}
p_a2: {d1, d2, d3, ...}
...
```

**Group B**

```
p_b1: {d1, d2, d3, ...}
p_b2: {d1, d2, d3, ...}
...
```

Where

p_a1, p_a2, ... are people in group A

p_b1, p_b2, ... are people in group B

d1, d2, ... are readings taken every day.

The question that I am trying to answer is, can the readings collected every day distinguish Group A and Group B significantly.

How can I set up a hypothesis test for this scenario.

Any help and pointers to blogs/papers is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you thought about a mixed effects regression model with random intercepts for  people? If not then what have you considered?

Comment: d1, d2, etc... are numerical value or the name of the readings?

Comment: @RobertLong I am relatively new to hypothesis testing. I considered using T-test by putting all observations/readings from all days of group 1 people into one set and all observations/readings from all days of group 2 people into another set. But that didn't sound right to me. So that's why I posted here for guidance.

Comment: @AbdoulHaki the 'd1', 'd2' are numerical values. For each day a reading is collected which is a numerical value.

Comment: You seem to have repeated measures within people, so this means the observations are not independent and so a t test is not appropriate. A mixed model with random intercepts for people may be appropriate.

Comment: You can also do an ANOVA with repeated measures.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I will read up on both "mixed model with random intercepts" and "ANOVA with repeated measures".